# Excel - If cells in a column contain a certain value, how can I add the values of the adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider this spreadsheet:

[image]

For all the cells in column A that contain the value "Y", how would I add the adjacent cells in column B together?

This is what I've tried so far to no avail, assuming COLUMN__A and COLUMN__B are defined names of cells in those columns:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",COLUMN__A)),SUM(COLUMN__B),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"*Y*",B1:B100)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",A1:A100))*(B1:B100))
```

both case insensitive.

Case sensitive formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("Y",A1:A100))*(B1:B100))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, only I changed the ranges to the names of the arrays. Thank you :)